# Switch AWS EC2 Instance from sql server enterprise to standard

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, sql-server

I'm trying to downgrade my ec2 instance from sql enterprise to sql standard or express, the thing i wanna keep the server content and i can't start from scratch.
i've tried uninstalling sql server and change the instance type, but i get this error message "Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition is not supported for the instance type" since i started the instance with sql server enterprise.
how can i downgrade the instance to standard or express ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [isn't possible](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=63321). You'll need to export your data, create a new instance, then import the data into the new instance.

Comment: Can you please tell a bit more about exporting data ?

Comment: I don't know anything about SQL Server sorry. Use whatever tools MS provides to export schema and data, then the same tools to import back in - Google should find them. If you need help with that please ask a question on the [Stack Exchange DBA site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you for the help, i think i can backup the database and import it somewhere else, what i don't know is if it's possible to export the rest of the os content to another ec2 instance avoiding "the instance type" error i'm getting on aws

Comment: What is "OS content"? Servers have applications and data. Install the applications, transfer the data, go.

Comment: i just was looking for an easy way to do it i guess, thank you